# Can Azure Data Factory be used to generate a CSV in an Azure Blob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

Can Azure Data Factory be used to extract data from an Azure SQL DB and dump it in to an Azure Blob? Or would something like that be better suited for a manual operation processed in C# via a WebJob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, yes.

Check out the following documentation for v2 ... [Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) ... or for v1 ... [Move data by using Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-data-movement-activities)